# How does new operator knows how much size needs to be allocated for specific class

Tags: c++, new-operator

In case of malloc function for memory allocation we specify the size we want to allocate like

```
void *malloc(8);
```

but in case of new we do not specify the size like below

```
Foo *fo = new Foo();
```

so, my question is how does new operator function knows the size it needs to allocated for object. Please explain, what happens behind the scene?

Comment: ```sizeof(data type)``` tells the size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has already seen the definition of `Foo`, so it knows how much memory is needed. `new Foo` turns into, essentially, two operations: `operator new(sizeof Foo)` to allocate the memory, followed by construction of a `Foo` object in the newly allocated space.

Comment: Hi Pete, Could you please provide some reference for the above detailed answer? Because, i want to read more about it and i am interested in details of the stuff like the one above. So, please provide me a link or a book name form where i can learn more about c++.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way as `malloc`. `operator new` takes a parameter that specifies the number of bytes to allocate.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

You do not need to specify the size manually, as the compiler will automatically pass in the size of the type when using `new`. For this to happen, the type has to be a complete type (you cannot use `new` with an incomplete type).

Comment: Be careful here: there's a difference between the "new operator", which is a language construct, and "operator new", which is a library function. In `new Foo`, the `new` is the new operator, not operator new. With "operator new" you **do** have to specify the size manually; with the new operator, the compiler figures it out, and calls operator new with the appropriate value.